# wordpress paging on custom loop - doesn't count farer than /page/2 and only displays the first posts

Tags: php, wordpress, paging

It seems that this question has already been asked very often, but after looking at tons of different answers and trying out different things I can't find the solution.

The problem: If I click on the next-Link the Url is changed to .../page/2 and there only the posts from the first page are displayed and no prev link also when I click on the next-Link again the url doesn't change.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
                    global $the_query, $paged;
                    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    $query_args = array(
                        'post_type' =>$current_post_type,
                        'cat' => get_cat_ID($current_category),
                        'posts_per_page' => 5,
                        'paged' => $paged
                        );

                    $the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

                ?>



            <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :?>
            <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
              <meta itemprop="url" content="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <br/>
                <h2 itemprop="headline" > <a href="the_permalink()"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <label>Author : <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person" ><span itemprop="name"><?php echo is_page($object_id) ? 'Yaez Verlag GmbH' : get_the_author(); ?></span></span></label>
                <label>Date : <?php echo get_the_date( 'c', $object_id ); ?> </label>
                <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="<?php echo get_the_date( 'c', $object_id ); ?>">
                <meta itemprop="dateModified" content="<?php echo get_the_date( 'c', $object_id ); ?>">
                <br/>
                <label itemprop="description"><?php echo wp_trim_words(the_excerpt()); ?> </label>
                <br/>

                <!--Image and Content-->

            <?php endwhile;?>

            <?php
                next_posts_link('Next', $the_query ->max_num_pages);
                previous_posts_link('Previous', $the_query ->max_num_pages);
            ?>

            <?php else: ?>
              <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: can you check what get_query_var('paged') returns on second page

Comment: it returns 0 on the first and also on the second page

Comment: try with $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

Comment: nothing changed, the only difference is what I get from mthe get_query_var('page') and that's nothing

Comment: sorry, still not sure why you don't have pagination, so I will suggest one more thing, try to remove $the_query and add $wp_query as global. And after that add: $q = ($query) ? $query : $wp_query; and change the $the_query->max_num_pages to $q->max_num_pages;

Comment: i changed all $the_query to $q, when I try to run it, I now get the error that $query is an undefined variable

Comment: no, no, you have to leave all the $the_query, remove only the global one, and on the same place add global $wp_query

Comment: ok, I changed it back and only changed the other things as you told me, $query is still an undefined variable